# CSS/JS Lazy Loading Background Images (White Flicker)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been trying to lazy load background images, by initially having a low res image which then gets swapped out to a high res one. I've tried a few different lazy loaders, but they all seem to have the same issue - when the image swaps there is a flicker. I've used Yall Lazy Image Loader, and added some modifications so that the image is actually loaded before, being applied to the background image - however there is still a brief white flicker of the image changing. It's more noticeable in Firefox, and happens when the image isn't cached.

Any ideas? Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/kehza/pen/PoPKZBa

```
newImg.onload = function () {
    this.backgroundTarget.classList.remove(lazyBackgroundClass);
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hardly noticable even in Firefox with this example, for me, but I suppose it could show more intense a real-live scenario. I guess “painting” the image still takes a moment, even when it has loaded. Maybe applying multiple background images, so that the low-res version still sits “underneath” the high-res one, could help fix this. (Probably won’t work so well when transparency gets involved, but maybe the low-res version could then be removed again with a bit of a timeout.)

Comment: It's unfortunately more noticeable on a 'busier' site, hm that could work - I'll need to think of a way to do this however (currently it's just a class that determines it, so removing would be tricky).

Answer (score 1):

Rendering both elements to the DOM first and later changing the opacity values should be the most performant because the browser will not paint or composite the layers again.  You can leverage the new [`"loading=lazy"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading) attribute and the browser will do that work for you.  The code below can be tweaked to use background images instead of inline images.  Consider the [`will-change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) attribute on `.wrapper` if you still seeing flickering.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="lowres" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0254/2426/5278/files/Suited-Racer_200x.jpg" />
  <img class="highres" loading="lazy" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0254/2426/5278/files/Suited-Racer_1920x.jpg" />
</div>
```

**js**

```
document.querySelectorAll('img.highres').forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('load', e => {
    img.parentElement.classList.add('highres-loaded'))
  })
})
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;

  /* set fixed size for your page */
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.highres {
  opacity: 0;
}
.highres-loaded .lowres {
  opacity: 0;
}
.highres-loaded .highres {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the loading lazy attribute with current browser support, the image will still load but their will be no lazy loading, it will start loading on page load. I'd still use a javascript fallback incase the image isn't visible on screen on load so it can be deferred. https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr